# spring boot 3 - digest authentication not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am not able to create a simple rest API with digest authentication with spring boot 3. It was working with version 2, but with a different configuration, because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not present anymore.

I create simple GitHub repository with the sample:

https://github.com/martinspudich/spring-boot-3-digest

I will appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you in advance.

I create simple HelloController:

```
package com.example.springboot3digest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And WebSecurityConfig:

```
package com.example.springboot3digest.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
                    request.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint()))
                .addFilterBefore(digestAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsService), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint result = new DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        result.setRealmName("My App Realm");
        result.setKey("3028472b-da34-4501-bfd8-a355c42bdf92");
        return result;
    }

    DigestAuthenticationFilter digestAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DigestAuthenticationFilter result = new DigestAuthenticationFilter();
        result.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        result.setAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
        return result;
    }
}
```

I was following spring.io documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/digest.html

But authentication is not working. When I try to authenticate it returns the error 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DigestAuthenticationFilter` does not generate "authenticated" tokens  unless you explicitly tell it to do so as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/DigestAuthenticationFilter.html#setCreateAuthenticatedToken(boolean)).

Add the line:

```
 result.setCreateAuthenticatedToken(true);
```

to your `DigestAuthenticationFilter` instantiation:

```
    DigestAuthenticationFilter digestAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DigestAuthenticationFilter result = new DigestAuthenticationFilter();
        result.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        result.setCreateAuthenticatedToken(true);
        result.setAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion set result.setCreateAuthenticationToken(trueo); solved my issue with digest authentication.